# Keyboard getting dismissed automatically when a button is clicked on the page

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have a text box which has a send button beside it. Whenever i type anything in text box and click on send button, keyboard is getting dismissed. But i want to clear the text box and not dismiss the keyboard. If I manually set the focus, i can clearly see keyboard getting dismissed and opening again effect.

How can i achieve this.

The following is the code snippet which i have tried:

**xaml:**

```
    "Button Grid.Row="1" Tapped="Button_Tapped" Content="click"/>  
    "TextBox x:Name="textbox" Grid.Row="2" Width="100" />
```

**xaml.cs**

```
private void Button_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)  
   {  
        textbox.Text = "";  
        textbox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In UWP apps, `TextBox` now has a button to clear the text. You should try this build-in method before implement on your own.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the input. But irrespective of how i clear the textbox, keyboard is getting dismissed as soon as i click on the button. i dont want the keyboard to be dismissed

Comment: When you click the button or tapping anything outside the TextBox, the TextBox will lost focus and the keyboard dismiss as expected. So think of using the build-in feature.

Answer (score 0):

in the TextBox usercontrol, there is a isTabStop property. set that to false.

It would work. No need of other handling like setting focus, etc.

Vote up if it works

Cheers